# Ranking volcanic rocks influence to geothermal suitability?

Tags: geology, volcanology, geothermal-heat

I am not a geologist/geology student but I want to quickly know the influence of volcanic rock type to geothermal suitability. I have read read some journals and online articles but it seems there are a lot of ways different mappers/researchers name geologic unit. What I am trying to do is rank types of volcanic rocks ex. the legend on the image to most influential to less influential to the geothermal suitability. A direct answer is cool but also welcome articles or readings regarding this. Thanks!

Legend:
[image]

Comment: What is "geothermal suitability "?

Comment: This appears to be a stratigraphic succession from the Philippines. Geothermal energy is available in many different geological contexts,  but simplistically one might expect it to be most common in the youngest volcanic rocks and active volcanic systems.

Comment: There are different ways to exploit geothrmal energy, using the natural gradient in an area or a heatpump into an aquifer come to my mind. Wouldn't it have to be checked in any individual case ?

Comment: geothermal suitability - in my context is contextualizing the potential of geothermal resources in the area, so I want to know, from my list which rocks have more influence such that there is higher possibility of geothermal resources

Comment: geothermal suitability in your definition (pretty much any definition) is a system problem. you can't look at an individual rock type or lithology in isolation. the different styles of system that @Earthworm gives examples of can be formed from a wide variety of geology and tectonic setting.

Comment: I want to use GIS along with multiple data to map potential geothermal areas such as this: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0375650509000698. Would volcanic rocks a good indicator of possible geothermal fields?

Comment: What type of volcanic rock should I look into? Such that my map can filter which areas have higher potential?